# convert array of key value pair to one object

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to convert the following array of key, value pairs to one single object.

```
       arr = [ { '/a': { component: [Function] },
            '/a/1': { component: [Function] },
            '/a/2': { component: [Function] },
            '/a/2/1': { component: [Function] },
            '/ab/2/1': { component: [Function] },
            '/b/1': { component: [Function] },
            '/b/login/register': { component: [Function] } },

             { '/ac': { component: [Function] },
            '/a/1': { component: [Function] } },
            ]
```

Convert the above object to

```
   obj = { '/a': { component: [Function] },
        '/a/1': { component: [Function] },
        '/a/2': { component: [Function] },
        '/a/2/1': { component: [Function] },
        '/ab/2/1': { component: [Function] },
        '/b/1': { component: [Function] },
        '/b/login/register': { component: [Function] } }
```

### Update

When there are duplicate keys, we like to log the warning while we merge the array object into an object.

Comment: Simply `obj = arr[0]`, if it's the only one object in your array

Comment: There are array of those objects, we need merge to one object. And if we have duplicated keys it should warn when overwriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const obj = {};

for(let row of arr) { 
  for(let key in row) {
    if(key === 'component') {
      continue
    }
    if(obj[key]) {
      console.warn('duplicate key', key)
    }
    obj[key] = row[key]
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```